# How to draw smooth(lines connected without any breaks) lines over google map in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am building a path tracing application on Android. This particular activity will receive position and whenever I get a position, I will join the last point with the current point. With this, I am getting the path but it is not smooth at joints.

A is something I am getting.
B is what I am trying to achieve.

A

```
   ________________
  |________________
|  |
|  |
```

B

```
 ________________
|________________
|  |
|  |
```

The problem is because I draw lines with 2 points. When google draws 3 points, the joint is connected properly. I am looking for a way something other than drawing 3 points instead of 2.

I am adding points to polyline

```
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
polylineOptions.add(lastPosition);
polylineOptions.add(currentPosition);
polylineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
polylineOptions.width(8);

mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

I also tried to set polylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND) but not much improvement.

Comment: For two points you should be using `startCap` with `SquareCap` which " is squared off after extending half the stroke width beyond the start".  The default `startCap` is `ButtCap` which "is squared off exactly at the start ".

Comment: Thanks. This is a nice option. Unfortunately, I cannot use this as this is not supported by my map version!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`JointType`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/JointType) affects segments of one polyline, not separate polylines. So do not draw path with lines of 2 points - draw entire path as one polyline. Something like that:

```
// add polyline to map (once) and save reference to it in polyLine variable
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
polylineOptions.add(lastPosition);
polylineOptions.add(currentPosition);
polylineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
polylineOptions.width(8);
Polyline polyLine = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

...
// every time when currentPosition updated
List<LatLng> polyLinePoints = polyLine.getPoints();   // get polyline points
polyLinePoints.add(currentPosition);                  // add currentPosition to polyline points
polyLine.setPoints(polyLinePoints);                   // update polyline points
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not working for me because my version doesn't support setPoints().

Comment: @raj Hmm, its strange. [`.setPoints()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline#setPoints(java.util.List%3Ccom.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng%3E)) supported by [`Polyline`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html) class "from the box". Please double check your code: may be you call `setPoints()` on wrong object.